# Are there android intents to add data to Google keep

Tags: android, android-intent

Are there android intents to add data to [Google keep](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.keep)?

Comment: PackageExplorer lists all intent-filters defined in apps in your device

Comment: I looked deeply, but didn't find anything. I guess there is no way to do this, since Google didn't publish about that...Actually I didn't know about this app...

Comment: Maybe you could use this page: https://drive.google.com/keep/
But as I read in the official blog of Google Keep (http://googleblog.blogspot.com.es/2013/03/google-keepsave-whats-on-your-mind.html), they are still adding things. So it could be possible soon.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is possible via new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)!
There is a technique to programmatically select the appropriate application instead of showing the possibilities.
Testet.

Comment: What kind of information does this allow you to send to Google Keep?

Comment: so far only tested for text but Intent.ACTION_SEND normally also accepts fields for media:
  intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, mmsUri);
  intent.setType("IMAGE");

Answer (score 2):

I have the confirmation from the Android team. As they answer here about some other things, a project member said that THERE IS NOT Google Keep API.

https://code.google.com/p/dashclock/issues/detail?can=1&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Component%20Summary%20Stars%20Status%20TargetRelease&groupby=&sort=-id&id=380

So I assume, that there is no way to pass information to the app or not a known one.

Comment: Actually, you received confirmation from a Googler, but AFAIK @RomanNurik is on the Android team (as a developer evangelist), not on the Google Keep team.

Comment: Sorry, you are completely right @CommonsWare. Anyway, the information comes from a valid source :)

Comment: According to this: https://plus.google.com/112893701314508522131/posts/HBxpoEktV7E I think any integration will come via the Google Drive API.

Comment: Good to know, since this apps looks quite interesting. Thanks for the info @Nik