# Is there an android Intent to add data to google keep?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, google-keep

I have a shopping list app and i want that the user can transfer his shopping list to google keep.

Is there a way i could do that with an  Intent or an API?
It would appreciate if you could put a link to a tutorial

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are there android intents to add data to Google keep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15553784/are-there-android-intents-to-add-data-to-google-keep)

Comment: i saw that before i asked this, but i hoped that with more recent answers, there might be some solutions